# multiply columns in two different tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have just started using Power BI and I am having trouble multiplying two columns that are in different tables. I have created a relationship between the tables and have tried different formulas that have not worked.

I have a table that is called h_reserva and a table called cambio divisas. I want to add a column on the table h_reserva that is the product of the column 'importe' in h_reserva and 'GBPEUR' in cambio divisas.

The last thing I tried was Medida = RELATED(h_reserva[importe])*RELATED('cambio divisas'[GBPEUR])

Does anybody know how I can modify the formula so that it works? Any help is appreciated :)
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **calculated column** in h_riserva should work

```
Medida = h_reserva[importe] * RELATED('cambio divisas'[GBPEUR])
```

if the relationship has been set up properly.

Comment: Is there anything unclear with the anwer?